# Android Currentview fragment by Tag giving null every time

Tags: android

In my android application i am using fragments and i wnat to get the displayed fragment by tag for that i am using below code to get the fragment by tag and i am using below code to replacing the current fragment with another fragment i am now understanding what is the wrong in my code so any one guide my to correct way.

```
DigitalDisplayFragment myDigitalDisplayFragment = (DigitalDisplayFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("DisplayFragment"); 



FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.simple_fragment, displayFragment, "DisplayFragment");
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
```

Comment: post your stack trace

Comment: in my console it's not showing any thing. 03-08 15:03:33.415: I/System.out(32754): Digital Display*************************
03-08 15:03:35.778: D/memalloc(32754): ion: Unmapping buffer

Comment: you can find the fragment by its id also try getSupportFragmentManager().findViewById(R.id.yourfragmentid), try it

Comment: even though i tried with your hint then also not working. Any how thanks for your support and valuable time.